# Change Back color of Image using combo box and save the data to data grid view

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I was able to change the BackColor of the image using the text I input in the ComboBox but when I save that data in a data grid, the back color is not changing.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        On Error GoTo SaveErr
        MachineHistoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Update(HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
        MessageBox.Show("OK Complete")
    SaveErr:
        Exit Sub
        Dim tempcolor4 As String
        Dim tempcolor1 As String

        tempcolor4 = ComboBox4.Text
        tempcolor1 = ComboBox1.Text

        If tempcolor4.Equals("Running") And tempcolor1.Equals("1") Then
            Form2.PictureBox15.BackColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf tempcolor4.Equals("Stop") And tempcolor1.Equals("1") Then
            Form2.PictureBox15.BackColor = Color.Red
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
            ComboBox4.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'HistoryDataSet.Machine_History' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'HistoryDataSet.Machine_History' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'HistoryDataSet.Machine_History' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        MachineHistoryBindingSource.MovePrevious()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        MachineHistoryBindingSource.AddNew()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        MachineHistoryBindingSource.MoveNext()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Form15.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exiting the method before setting the color.

```
On Error GoTo SaveErr
        MachineHistoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Update(HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
        MessageBox.Show("OK Complete")
    SaveErr:
        Exit Sub '<--- Right here
```

In vb.net we have structured error handling with Try...Catch...Finally...End Try

```
Try
    MachineHistoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Update(HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
    MessageBox.Show("OK Complete")
Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
     Exit Sub
End Try
```

Comment: i removed  "on Error Goto SaveErr" and SaveErr. because there's an error occurred and right now the back color is changing but the problem data does not save in data grid.